# disable function, If parent div has more than 1 child div

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript which checks every 5 seconds if a parent div has 1 child div or more than 1 child div

**HTML :**

```
<div id="program-days">
    <div class="row">program 1</div>
    <div class="row">program 2</div>
    <div class="row">program 3</div>
</div>
```

How I can disable the function below, if `#program-days` has only 1 child div :

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
checkProgramData();
checkProgram = setInterval(checkProgramData, checkProgramInterval);
});
```

Can I use a script something like this? :

```
setInterval(function(){
if(jQuery('div#program-days .row').length > 1){
    // enable function
    }
else{
    // disable function
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why not try your idea and then report back if you can't get it working?

Comment: have you tried it ?

Comment: The approach to this problem is pretty weird. What you probably want to do is always have the function available, and within the function execute code depending on the number of divs.

Comment: Your approach of DOM changing events is not correct. Take this question as guide
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Answer (score 0):

Just give your interval a variable name:

```
var programDaysInterval = setInterval(...);
```

In the else of your function you can stop the interval by it's name:

```
clearInterval(programDaysInterval);
```

Complete example:

```
$(function() {
    function checkProgram() {
        if($("#program-days").find('.row').length > 1) {
            console.log('stop');
            clearInterval(checkProgramInterval);
        } else {
            console.log('just keep going');
        }
    }

    var checkProgramInterval = setInterval(checkProgram,500);
});
```

Comment: As this looks to be done on document load, do you need the else?

Comment: @Pete just providing the solution to stop the interval. If the data comes from the document load you don't need a interval at all

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Jquery for this. This is a possible solution:

The first one is a basic if else statement, the other one stops the interval whenever there is less than 1 row. Was this the answer you were looking for?

```js
//Basic solution
setInterval(() => {
 if(document.querySelectorAll('#program-days > .row').length > 1){
  
  }else{
   
  }
},1000)

// Stopping interval / function if not true
let interval = setInterval(() => {
 if(document.querySelectorAll('#program-days > .row').length > 1){
   
  }else{
   interval.clearInterval()
  }
},1000)
```

```html
<div id="program-days">
    <div class="row">program 1</div>
    <div class="row">program 2</div>
    <div class="row">program 3</div>
</div>
```